# Outbound port 25 connections timing out all of a sudden: Centos 6.6 & postfix; hacked?

Tags: postfix, centos6.6

I have been running a Centos email/web server for years, with a Linode Xen server the last 4 years with almost no trouble.

Since sometime yesterday I have not been able to connect to outbound email (port 25) servers. The mail queue is building up. Other weird things:

- I can traceroute on port 25 to gmail servers and complete, but time out when connecting outbound to these servers
- I just did **yum update** earlier this afternoon
- I was getting IPV6 connections trying to be set up until I turned off IPV6 in sysctl
- I can receive inbound mail on port 25 just fine, just can't forward it out.
- I'm getting dynamic changes in my iptables, for examples:

  ```
  Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
  target     prot opt source               destination         
  DROP       all  --  cpe-188-129-114-96.dynamic.amis.hr  anywhere            
  DROP       all  --  190.40.173.185       anywhere            
  DROP       all  --  5.200.193.129        anywhere            
  DROP       all  --  206.47.254.202       anywhere            

  Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
  target     prot opt source               destination         
  DROP       all  --  cpe-188-129-114-96.dynamic.amis.hr  anywhere            
  DROP       all  --  190.40.173.185       anywhere            
  DROP       all  --  5.200.193.129        anywhere            
  DROP       all  --  206.47.254.202       anywhere            

  Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
  target     prot opt source               destination
  ```

Any ideas? Have I been hacked?

Comment: 1) Are you using any dynamic firewall updating thingy, or greylisting?
2) Is it possible that your ISP has blocked outbound port 25 traffic for you?

Answer (score 1):

Just a few things

1. Those are probably spammer addresses but what I think is weird is that the iptables are set to not connect, not to disallow the connection. Maybe you have some sort of security program/firewall/IDS blocking IP addresses?
2. Consider [flushing your iptables](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-iptables-how-to-flush-all-rules.html) and planning out what you think your firewall should look like. If you have a firewall program see if it's interfering. If a bunch of unsavory servers are trying to connect to yours, chances are your server is locking down. I don't see the real benefit in hackers taking out your functionality. Most use SMTP servers to send out spam so they benefit from it functioning.

EDIT: I say those are spammer addresses because the 206.x.x.x address is notorious.

Comment: I talked to the ISP and they are hands-off: no firewalling from them.  I also tried flushing iptables and they just came back shortly .... I worked around this by creating a secondary MX host that I'm routing mail through but I would still like to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: @MarkMcWiggins where does the traceroute die when you try to traceroute to these servers?

Comment: Traceroute works (with some apparent delay) but telnet fails: `traceroute to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com (173.194.219.26), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  23.92.24.2 (23.92.24.2)  0.357 ms  0.528 ms  0.692 ms
 2  10ge7-6.core3.fmt2.he.net (65.49.10.217)  0.168 ms  0.180 ms  0.153 ms
 3  10ge10-1.core1.sjc2.he.net (184.105.222.14)  6.314 ms  8.659 ms  8.523 ms
 

12  * * *
13  * * *

19  ya-in-f26.1e100.net (173.194.219.26)  60.338 ms * *
-bash-4.1$ telnet  alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25
Trying 173.194.219.26...
telnet: connect to address 173.194.219.26: Connection timed out`